# How to get Require.js to play nicely with browserify?

Tags: requirejs, browserify

I have an app that uses browserify to load modules.  Famo.us uses require.js.  Is there a version that can integrate with browserify?  Or is there a way to load modules using the require.js style?

Comment: +1 I really hope that famo.us migrates to browserify!

Answer (score 0):

What I did was just drop the require.js syntax using recursive regexes.  Specifically (.*)\Z will trim the last line.